# How do validate a group of radio buttons?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a online survey and I am using jquery validation on it.

So each question has 4 options, where each option is a radio button.

When I am building my jquery validatio rules, how should I reference them?

Each question option has an ID and name.

Below is what I am doing so far, and it isn't working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $("#myForm").validate({
           rules : {     
               someQuestionId123 : {required : true }
           });
  });
```

Where someQuestionId123  is the **name** of the radio button element.

Comment: You're improperly closing your `rules` with a `});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're improperly closing your rules with a `});`...

```
rules : {     
    someQuestionId123 : {required : true }
});
```

---

Using the jQuery Validate plugin's `.validate()` method, you **must** reference them by `name`.

Since a group of `radio` buttons should all share the same `name`, you're already doing it properly (after fixing an issue with your brackets)...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#myForm").validate({
        rules: {     
            someQuestionId123: { // <-- NAME attribute
                required: true 
            }
        }  // <-- right here, you incorrectly had '});'
    });
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<input type="radio" name="someQuestionId123" value="one" />
<input type="radio" name="someQuestionId123" value="two" />
<input type="radio" name="someQuestionId123" value="three" />
<input type="radio" name="someQuestionId123" value="four" />
```

**DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/5dsJQ/

---

And finally, your latest jsFiddle is broken because you have special characters, such as `-`, inside your `name`...

```
rules: {     
    someQuestionId-123: { 
        required: true 
    }
}
```

[As per the "reference docs"](http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/), you need to enclose the name in quotes to fix this issue...

```
rules: {     
    "someQuestionId-123": { 
        required: true 
    }
}
```

In general, if you're using these names as JavaScript targets, you'd avoid naming with dashes, `-`, because JavaScript could sometimes interpret them as minus signs.  For jQuery Validate, the quotation marks will get around this problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/RB4NU/12/

Comment: But I am using the name not the id value?

Comment: @user1361315, since your `name` contains special characters like `-`, you need to enclose the `name` within quotation marks. See:   http://jsfiddle.net/RB4NU/12/

Comment: In case you read this, how can I change the message like say in another language for spanish speaking people?

Comment: @user1361315, statically or dynamically... you haven't provided enough details to answer that briefly.  However, that's totally off-topic to this question/answer and we're not supposed to be having a long discussion or answering lots of unrelated followups in the comments section.  You should start a new question for that (assuming you've already searched SO).